# Shifting database from MySQL to Postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-migration

I have a database in MySQL which can be accessed using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studios. I have a .bak file of that database and I want to shift this database to Postgres.

I went to the command line and I opened the directory of my Postgres to the bin folder from the program files, and I wrote the command :

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres < (directory of the .bak file)'
```

I got the following error on running the above command:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TAPE"
> LINE 1: TAPE

Can someone please explain why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Apparently your ".bak file" contains a SQL statement that is not understood by Postgres. Without seeing the actual statement that failed, this is impossible to answe.r

Comment: You can not access a MySQL server from within Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - that only works for Microsoft SQL Server. Are you trying to restore a **Microsoft SQL Server**" .bak file to Postgres? That won't work. A .bak file is a binary file that is only understood by SQL Server.